# How to indicate a user is a full member or just a regular member?

Tags: icons, social-media, status

I'm looking for some nice ways to visualize whether a user is a full member or a regular member. Assume a Facebook-style website with full membership option.

The profiles will be displayed as blocks of 80x80 with image and name in a box below.

Comment: What's the difference between the two membership types that would affect a users experience?

Comment: Is it like the difference between a regular LinkedIn member vs. someone who has upgraded to a Pro Account? Is there some sort of status conferred on a paying member vs. non-paying participant?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to display this information on a list of profiles?

Who is interested in this information?

Is there any actual benefit to other users?

For example, knowing someone is paid up LinkedIn member as opposed to someone who's just using a free account doesn't really affect *me* as another LinkedIn user. It doesn't change the way *I* can interact with that user. So in this scenario there is no utility to having that information displayed at all.

However, for a system administrator or marketing manager for the company running the site then having that information could well have utility and would need to be displayed to those users. In this case a simple "+" icon or the word "Pro"/"Full" overlaid in one corner of the image would work, as would changing the background colour of the user name perhaps.

If the goal is to convert free members to paid members then that's certainly a valid reason for differentiating the users. In this case, however you display it, some way of highlighting the benefits would be useful - this could be a tooltip or a link to the "become a full member and gain these rewards page". This could be from the icon I mentioned earlier.

Looking at this slightly differently on Stack Exchange where a "full" member is one that participates in the site posting questions and answers rather than just reading the content having their reputation score and badge totals next to their names is useful to me as user. It gives me clues as to how knowledgeable and helpful this person is, it also indicates whether I'm likely to find them in chat etc.

To sum up - work out your use cases and why this information needs to be displayed and to who. Once you have this the "how" might become clearer - or at least you can ask a more focused question.

Comment: The status afforded by having a gold star next to your name doesn't affect someone else, but it does affect *you*, and that's worth something. And in the case of Stack Exchange, it does affect me - I know you have 2 gold badges and therefore aren't likely are worth listening to.

Comment: @Rahul - good point. I suppose it boils down to what your definition of "full" membership is.

Comment: To be fair, SE badges have nothing to do with membership. They're achievement/XP/karma markers more comparable to the user labels you find on many forums indicating how many posts they've made. It does grant extra privileges, but that's not why they're meaningful. OTOH, my premium dA membership isn't meaningful to me because my name displays differently in chats or I get a little premium icon next to my avatar. It's meaningful because I have access to extra features. So the proverbial "gold star" _denotes_ worth but doesn't confer it. It's there mostly for marketing.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - that's why I put "full" in quotes. As I tried to point out you should only display this information if it affects how *you* can interact with other users.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté You're glossing over social proof and peer status. If I can show a badge that says I'm special, pro, VIP or whatever, and I'm extremely committed to the community, that can be *very* valuable. Don't underestimate it.

Comment: @Rahul: I suppose that's true. I guess it depends on the nature of the community. For some sites, having a paid membership in itself is significant, and it people may take you more seriously for it (or not take you seriously if you're not committed enough to purchase a membership), but on other sites (e.g. Slashdot) reputation is pretty much the sole status indicator.

Comment: I strongly agree with @ChrisF, the status difference should only be displayed in the situations that matter - mainly system admins and marketing people.

Comment: Thx for the interesting view on this, its indeed a bit more complex then my post assumed. A full or free member is nothing more than a free non paying and a full paying member, the full member has some small advantages over the free one and can use the service unlimited. It seems that changing the background is indeed the best way to go on this, since its less interruptive and the full members will always be less than the free so it won't create a strange effect or layout disturbance in the profile listing pages ;p

Comment: I think display of this information does have an effect; it affects a site's culture.  The indication that some users have paid, promotes the fact that a paid option exists.  Flickr Pro is an example of this concept - knowing that user has pro-membership might not affect the way we interact with other users, but it serves as a tacit reminder that the option to upgrade exists.

Comment: @codeinthehole - that may be true, but doesn't fundamentally affect this answer - once you have your reason for displaying the information *then* the way to display that information should become clearer

Comment: @ChrisF; I think indicating whether the user has pro membership can be useful, but it should be thought about in terms of larger goals.  In this case, I don't think the main benefit is to site admins or marketers, when their interface is likely to be able to provide reports with required membership information.  In terms of the OP's question, I think the main goal is to increase conversion, and for this reason I don't think the answer provided is necessarily the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

A non obtrusive answer would be to use different color borders around the 80x80 image.  This works as long as your states (full/non-full) are few in number.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate profiles to show different membership status in a few ways (in order of what I would try were I in this situation):

- The classic "gold star" or other glyph.  Note that somebody seeing it for the first time might not know what it means other than "this one is special", but maybe that's ok.  We all had to learn what the SE moderator diamond means once.
- Changes in, rather than additions to, the rendering: border color (as suggested by Duane Gran), text color, text size, text styling (italics, bold, underlining), etc.  These have the same learnability issues as glyphs but do not (necessarily) affect your basic layout.  If profiles are text in a browser (as opposed to images), some text-styling changes might not play well with browser accessibility affordances.
- Text ("full" for full members, absent for regular?).  This has the advantage of more obvious meaning but the disadvantage of requiring more space (most likely) than anything else you might do.

Answer (score 1):

**Think about what you want to achieve by displaying this extra information about your users.**

Offering the information could be useful; it will potentially affect your site's internal culture by increasing your users' exposure to paid membership options - and the fact that paid membership exists.

Considering this further, one main benefit to providing 'pro' or 'full' status to paid members is the chance of increased conversion.

For this reason I would suggest:

- adding a postfix label - as a link - to each paid / full member's name.
- providing further information about paid membership via the postfix link.
- aiming to make the label reasonably unobtrusive to ensure it doesn't complete too strongly with site content for the attention of site visitors.

---

An example of this methodology in action can be seen via Flickr:

[image: Display of Pro users via Flickr]